# JS6 - How can I loop through an array of objects and filter where country = UK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, rxjs6

```js
const arr =[
            {
                id:1,
                name: 'Name',
                country: 'UK',
            },
            {
                id:2,
                name: 'Name',
                country: 'USA',
            },
            {
                id:3,
                name: 'Name',
                country: 'USA',
            },
            {
                id:4,
                name: 'Name',
                country: 'UK',
            },
        ];
```

Comment: [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `filter()`:

```js
const arr =[ { id:1, name: 'Name', country: 'UK', }, { id:2, name: 'Name', country: 'USA', }, { id:3, name: 'Name', country: 'USA', }, { id:4, name: 'Name', country: 'UK', }, ];

const res = arr.filter(e => e.country === 'UK');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `filter`

```js
const arr =[
            {
                id:1,
                name: 'Name',
                country: 'UK',
            },
            {
                id:2,
                name: 'Name',
                country: 'USA',
            },
            {
                id:3,
                name: 'Name',
                country: 'USA',
            },
            {
                id:4,
                name: 'Name',
                country: 'UK',
            },
        ];

const uk = arr.filter(item => item.country === 'UK')

console.log(uk)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()`

```
arr.filter(value => value.country === 'UK')
```